# class validator - 3D array

Tags: javascript, nestjs, class-validator

I'm trying to sent payload which in the form of :

```
{
  "name": {
    "ar": "مصر",
    "en": "EG"
  },
  "location": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [30.7939, 26.8206],
        [32.1597, 26.8206],
        [32.1597, 23.6345],
        [30.7939, 23.6345],
        [30.7939, 26.8206]
      ]
    ]
  },
  "addressesType": "Country"
}
```

I'm expecting that coordinates be an array of array of arrays each has exactly 2 number that represents longitude and latitude.

I have my location field validation like that:

```
/* eslint-disable lines-between-class-members */
/* eslint-disable @darraghor/nestjs-typed/validated-non-primitive-property-needs-type-decorator */
import { ArrayMaxSize, ArrayMinSize, ArrayNotEmpty, Equals, IsArray, IsNumber, IsOptional, IsString, ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';

export default class AddressLocationDto {
  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  @Equals('Polygon')
  type: string;

  @IsArray()
  @ArrayNotEmpty()
  @ArrayMinSize(1)
  @ArrayMaxSize(1)
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @IsArray()
  @ArrayNotEmpty()
  @ArrayMinSize(1)
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @IsArray()
  @ArrayNotEmpty()
  @ArrayMinSize(2)
  @ArrayMaxSize(2)
  @IsNumber({}, { each: true })
  coordinates: number[][][];
}
```

results in this error[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESeqC.png)

Comment: Are you sure it's `"location"` and not `"Location"`?

Comment: @AlanOmar yes, It's location